# How to use either this type or another based on props only? React Typescript Discriminating Unions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a componenet:

```js
type Base = {
    color: string
}

type Button = {
    to: string
} & Base

type Link = {
    link: string
    linkNewTab: boolean
} & Base

type ComponentProps = Button | Link 

export const Button: React.FC<ComponentProps> = (props) => {
    return (<>
        {props.link ? <Link newTab={props.linkNewTab}>...</Link> : props.to && <Button>...</Button>}
    </>)
}
```

- There is a base type with props which both types have in common.
- The Component should either has Button or Link type based on the given props. But if it has Link, these props are preferred.

**Typescript Error:**

```yaml
Property 'link' does not exist on type 'PropsWithChildren<ComponentProps>'.
  Property 'link' does not exist on type '{ to: string; } & Base & { children?: ReactNode; }'.ts(2339)
```

**What I don't want:**

- I can solve the problem by adding a type to the Base type and decide from their which props are allowed. I would like to automatically decide that based on props.

Information: `4.5.4 TypeScript Version`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are attempting to access a **value** at property which might not exist. Instead, you can check to see if that **property** exists in the object (by using the [`in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) operator) before trying to access its value. This will also discriminate the union:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAQghgZ2gXigbwFBSgYwPYA2eATgFxQLDECWAdgOYYC+A3BhqJLAK7DB60oqeEigAydFij9ylGg2ZsO4aABk6AayGxE0CZmwFNsqnUaHNAOQgB3ACpwARuUd5CEOLUXsAJhBwEcMTQ+LSUUGDEeGAI5DC8-IIAPlDqtBpKAPSZUHSUHj5QeABm0gAW1LEY1KUAFJHRCAB0RukAlOhMGNnYvb0AeoP93TkAClGQxKBQAOStGjNQPngQCFC0eMBQEAAelVsC0iqz8XyHKWkLTSO949EQUyCz84vLq+ub23vhh5zQM6dEjMmrUAEwAZnBAE42uweg0wLlBHhHAArap1OaaRZ0CITBAdAx4xpNfBEYhQHp4DRSBHNeaUnLU2n4lpWWwORyMoo0roQAiiIl00mEEjc5nYYX8cW8oA)

```ts
// instead of this:
if (props.link) {}
//        ^^^^
// Property 'link' does not exist on type 'Button | Link'.
//   Property 'link' does not exist on type 'Button'.(2339)

// prop in obj
if ('link' in props) {
  props.color // ok
  props.link // ok
  props.linkNewTab // ok
}
else {
  props.color // ok
  props.to // ok
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check whether the `link` property exists by using the `in` operator. This will narrow down the type without accessing the property, and so typescript will allow it:

```
<>
  {"link" in props ? (
    <Link newTab={props.linkNewTab}>...</Link>
  ) : (
    "to" in props && <Button>...</Button>
  )}
</>
```